# UISearchControll Searchbar Doesn't Animate into UINavigationBar

Tags: ios8, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a uisearchcontroller searchbar that I placed in my tableview.tableHeaderView. However, when I click on the searchbar it doesn't animate into the searchbar, instead it stays where it is. I've tried everything and I can't wrap my head around why this would be different in iOS8. Any help is much appreciated!!!!

And yes the navbar is part of a uinavigationcontroller

Heres the code:

```
drinksSC = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
drinksSC.searchResultsUpdater = self;
drinksSC.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
drinksSC.searchBar.delegate = self;
drinksSC.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
drinksSC.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
[drinksSC.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = drinksSC.searchBar;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of `drinksSC.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` to `YES`, and it will.

Or remove this line altogether, as the default value of this property is `YES` anyway.